# Add a reputation change summary to the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, reputation

While viewing the website on my smartphone I'll occasionally check the reputation change on my profile.

One thing that has bothered me repeatedly is that the mobile site shows reputation change on a per change basis (e.g. +5 for x, +35 for y...} but does not summarize the total change, making you have to add it up yourself which isn't too convenient.

Anyway, it would be a nice and simple fix to add a total/summary in the date header for total change of rep.

Comment: +1 Second that. Just an aggregation of today's gathered reputation would be more than helpful already :)

Comment: has been duplicated by [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138801/include-rep-total-for-the-day-on-mobile) however the latter question has more support